# Adding Repositories option is not available in Software Center in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-center

There is a difference between Software Centers of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS.
Software Center of 14.04 LTS is more convenient than 16.04 LTS as users can add third party software repository addresses.
It is my suggestion to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS developer provide same facility in 16.04 LTS for updating and adding software repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference, in 16.04 LTS you will have the Gnome-Software-Center instead of the Ubuntu-Software-Center.

As for adding repositories, this you always can do in `System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Other Software`